# looking for gem that flags datetime fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, rubygems

I got datetime filds **order_confirmed_at** and **completion_confirmed_at**

```
class CoolModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order_confirmed, completion_confirmed

  def order_confirmed
    order_confirmed_at.present?
  end

  def order_confirmed=(state)
    if state and order_confirmed_at.blank?
      self.order_confirmed_at = Time.now
    end
    order_confirmed_at.present?
  end

  def completion_confirmed
    completion_confirmed_at.present?
  end

  def completion_confirmed=(state)
    if state and completion_confirmed_at.blank?
      self.completion_confirmed_at = Time.now
    end
    completion_confirmed_at.present?
  end
end
```

...so in my view I can just check checkbox that order was confirmed and completed

Thing is: not only this is duplication, but this stuff obviously looks pretty standard. So in matter saving me time writing gem: **is there rails gem/engine doing this (or maybe part of Rails I'm not aware of) ??**

```
class CoolModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #something like this 
  acts_even_coller_on :order_confirmed_at, :completion_confirmed_at
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just override the setter method.

```
def confirmed_at=(value)
  super value == "true" ? confirmed_at || Time.now : nil
end
```

Comment: let say the order was confirmed 5.days ago, now the user updates the  form and he will also update his the time when he "confirmed" order. In other words this will act as updated_at attribute, rather than time track-able flag.

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite the value you can just check if the value is already set   value ? order_confirmed || Time.zone.now : nil

Comment: ...sorry for typo: "also update his the time "  should be "also updates order_confirmed_at time"

Comment: yeah, that will prettify the setter method so +1 for that (thx), but still ideally I should also have reader method like I described it in my question (so  when dealing with order_confirmed we will have boolean not time-date, and let the order_confirmed_at to deal with date-time)

Comment: I decided to use your way, at the end it makes sense. Only one little change to enable passing Time value in console, Updated in your answer